# How to edit a bone with a local axis?

Tags: rigging, bones, pose-mode

Coming from maya I'm a little bit confused with some rigging stuff in blender, got stuck on this one. Here i have a two bones finger, i have an armature axis display on, and want to move the head of the bone in the edit mode along the Y axis, so the finger stays straight, but the local grab orientation (and any over orientation) doesn't represent the armature axis orientation, what do i do wrong?
[image]

Comment: Yes you would expect to be able to move the bone's head or tail on its axis, that said you can create a custom transform orientation axis on the selected bone

Comment: To move a bone in its local axes, rather than the armature's local axes, set orientation space to "normal".  "Local" **should** be armature local space, and if it's not, I can't explain that.

Comment: @Nathan, yes it lacks logic here, but Normal works, you should answer

Answer (score 0):

If you change to pose mode it uses the local axis to rotate the bone, then if you need the changes you did in pose mode in edit mode you can click on pose-> apply -> apply pose as rest pose (kinda the same thing as freeze transforms in maya). Also if you want to make the bone longer along the local axis you can change the length in edit mode transform menu.[image][image]